# replacing the lines with the headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` in `pandas` like this small example:
small example:

```
 0       1       2       3       4         5          6
Probe   IRF2    PTEN    PRKACB  BBS1    PPARGC1B    ITGAE
20190606_CF     231.14  115.57  180.02  155.57  408.94  164.46
20190606_CF     340.19  240.4   396.13  133.05  142.12  247.96
```

I want to remove the 1st row and put the 2nd row as header. and in fact the 3rd row (of small example) would be the first row of data. 
here is the expected output:

```
Probe   IRF2    PTEN    PRKACB  BBS1    PPARGC1B    ITGAE
20190606_CF     231.14  115.57  180.02  155.57  408.94  164.46
20190606_CF     340.19  240.4   396.13  133.05  142.12  247.96
```

I am trying to do that in pandas using this code:

```
new = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
```

but it does not return the expected output. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: How is created DataFrame? Maybe is necessary remove `header=None` from `read_csv`

Comment: Add `skiprows=[0]` to `pandas.read_csv` and it will do the job for you :)